# Android Listview with multiple columns

Tags: c#, android, monodevelop

I'm trying to do a C# Android Listview that supports multiple columns.
I found some code how to do a Listview here: 
http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/

However this is Java code so I converted it to C# as follows:

```
        // List view control
        ListView list = (ListView) FindViewById(Resource.Id.mylist);
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> mylist = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        map.Add("Profit Centre", "Systems");
        map.Add("Last Updated", "16/02/2012 15:34");
        mylist.Add(map);
        map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        map.Add("Profit Centre", "IDTS");
        map.Add("Last Updated", "20/02/2012 10:26");
        mylist.Add(map);

        SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, Resource.Layout.list_item,new String[] {"Profit Centre", "Lasted Updated",}, new int[] { Resource.Id.columnA,  Resource.Id.columnB});

        list.Adapter = mSchedule;
```

The SimpleAdapter complains that the 2nd parameter is incorrect. It reports this

ERROR 1 =

The best overloaded method match for 'Android.Widget.SimpleAdapter.SimpleAdapter(Android.Content.Context, System.Collections.Generic.IList>, int, string[], int[])' has some invalid arguments

ERROR 2 =

Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList>'

Why is this? Please could you help me as I have researched using google to see if there are ways of creating a Listview (for Android) with multiple columns but cannot find any in C#, only Java code.

Thanks,

Andrew Ashcroft

Comment: Are you using c# for android development?

Comment: Yes I'm using MonoDevelop to code in C# for Android Development

Answer (score 1):

You have inconsistency between the definition of mylist and expected list in the Android `SimpleAdapter`

Change your code to the following;

```
         // List view control  
        ListView list = (ListView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.mylist);
        IList<IDictionary<string, object>> mylist = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>();
        IDictionary<string, object> map = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        map.Add("Profit Centre", "Systems");       
        map.Add("Last Updated", "16/02/2012 15:34");       
        mylist.Add(map);       
        map = new Dictionary<string, object>()>;      
        map.Add("Profit Centre", "IDTS");       
        map.Add("Last Updated", "20/02/2012 10:26");       
        mylist.Add(map);       

        SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, Resource.Layout.list_item,new String[] {"Profit Centre", "Lasted Updated",}, new int[] { Resource.Id.columnA,  Resource.Id.columnB});       

        ListAdapter = mSchedule;
```

If your activity implements ListActivity than you should replace the line

```
list.Adapter = mSchedule;
```

with

```
ListAdapter = mSchedule;
```

Regards,

Shalom Keynan

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is possible using CustomList adapter as described here:
http://redth.info/2010/10/12/monodroid-custom-listadapter-for-your-listview

I altered this so it just has two columns, profit centre and last updated.